# Pandas.plot(subplots=True) with 3 columns in each subplot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a DataFrame with 700 rows and 6 columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(700,6))
```

I can plot *all columns in a single plot* by calling:

```
df.plot()
```

And I can plot *each column in a single plot* by calling:

```
df.plot(subplots=True)
```

**How can I have two subplots with three columns each from my DataFrame?!**

Comment: This would most easily be done directly in `matplotlib` (in my opinion). Here is a great demo- https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general approach to plot a dataframe with n columns in each subplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(700,6))

col_per_plot = 3
cols = df.columns.tolist()
# Create groups of 3 columns
cols_splits = [cols[i:i+col_per_plot] for i in range(0, len(cols), col_per_plot)]  

# Define plot grid.
# Here I assume it is always one row and many columns. You could fancier...
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, len(cols_splits))
# Plot each "slice" of the dataframe in a different subplot
for cc, ax in zip(cols_splits, axarr):
    df.loc[:, cc].plot(ax = ax)
```

This gives the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the general solution.